# qgis composer doesn't lock filter properly

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm making a composer with 6 maps based on the same (postgis)layers and extent. The only thing that differs between them is the filter I put on two layers. I change the filter on the layers, then only refresh the map for that particular filter and lock the map. At the end it looks fine in the composer, but after exporting all maps have the same (last applied) filter. This also happens after refreshing the composer.

I'm using a clean install of QGIS 2.18.13 on macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: How did you lock the map?

Comment: lock layers & lock style for layers in the Item Properties

Comment: As a workaround, try to duplicate the layer after applying the filter and lock the layer and its style, then update the duplicate layer with the new filter, and see if that work.

Comment: There is a layer lock (which manages just the visibility of layers) and a style lock. There is no filter lock as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking a map in the print composer only locks which layers are displayed. It doesn't lock the filters. You will need to duplicate the layer and apply a different filter to each copy. Then you can use the layer visibility lock to control which layer is displayed in each map.

[image]

Note that this doesn't make extra copies of the source data. It simply displays the same source data multiple times.